# How can I Instantiate a model and dissociate the material/texture from another instance of the model?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So the title might not be perfect, but it's essentially what I want to do.

### My problem

I'm creating an app using Unity 2017.3.0f3 and Google's ARCore where you can select a model to place in the world and change the texture on the material as desired. The problem I'm having is that I can place a model with 1 texture on it, but when I change the texture on the `Ghost` model (in this case, the `Ghost` model floats around in the world on the ARCore `Plane` where a `Raycast` from the center of the screen collides with the `Plane`) it changes the texture on the already-placed model as well. See the screenshots below, taken seconds apart from screenshots on my phone:

1. I have placed a model (left/back) with the 'Lit' firepit texture, and the `Ghost` model is still 'Lit' (right/front):

[image]

2. I have clicked the 'Unlit' firepit texture in the list, and now both models have changed texture:

[image]

This is the code I wrote to change the `Ghost` to the selected model (it works, I've tested it with multiple models, but the demo currently only has 1), which is called when clicking on the model thumbnail in the bottom pane:

```
public void SetPlaceableModel(GameObject newModel)
{
    PlaceableModel = newModel;
    var pos = (Ghost != null) ? Ghost.transform.position : FirstPersonCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2f, Screen.height / 2f, -100f));
    var rot = (Ghost != null) ? Ghost.transform.rotation : Quaternion.identity;
    Destroy(Ghost);
    Ghost = Instantiate(PlaceableModel, pos, rot);
}
```

This is the code I wrote to change the texture on the `Ghost` model, which is called when clicking on the texture thumbnail in the top pane:

```
public void ChangeGhostTextures(TextureSet textureSet)
{
    SelectedTextureSet = textureSet;
    var materials = Ghost.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>().SelectMany(x => x.materials);
    foreach (var texture in textureSet.Textures.Where(x => !x.name.ToLower().Contains("normal")))
    {
        var normalTexture = textureSet.Textures.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == string.Format("{0}_Normal", texture.name));
        foreach (var material in materials.Where(x => x.name.Replace(" (Instance)", string.Empty) == texture.name))
        {
            material.SetTexture("_MainTex", texture);
            if (normalTexture != null)
            {
                material.SetTexture("_BumpMap", normalTexture);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the definition of `TextureSet`:

```
public class TextureSet : MonoBehaviour {
    public string SetName;
    public Texture Thumbnail;
    public List<Texture> Textures = new List<Texture>();
}
```

And this is the code I'm using to `Instantiate` the `Ghost` model into a new object and placing it on the ARCore `Plane` in the `Update()` method:

```
var productModel = Instantiate(Ghost, Ghost.transform.position, Ghost.transform.rotation);
productModel.GetComponent<PlaneAttachment>().Attach(hit.Plane);
```

As far as I can tell, and I don't know why this is, when I `Instantiate` the `Ghost` onto the `Plane`, the materials seem to be maintaining reference to the `Ghost` materials. I've tried changing the `ChangeGhsotTexture` to do this:

```
var _tex = Instantiate(texture) as Texture; //also tried 'as Texture2D'
material.SetTexture("_MainTex", _tex);
```

But then this happens when I change textures:

[image]

I've also tried to `Instantiate(material) as Material` and then set it that way, but the same thing happens (as the original issue, not the black texture):

```
material.SetTexture("_MainTex", texture);
if (normalTexture != null)
{
    material.SetTexture("_BumpMap", normalTexture);
}
var _mat = Instantiate(material) as Material;
//can't assign directly to `material` because it's the enumeration result
var assignableMaterial = materials.First(x => x.Equals(material));
assignableMaterial = _mat;
```

### Now here's the kicker

After placing a model down, if I click on the model thumbnail (bottom pane, which calls `SetPlaceableModel`), even when it's the same model that's already selected because it still calls `SetPlaceableModel`, it works**! I've tried calling `SetPlaceableModel` after placing the model in the `Update()` method, but it doesn't fix the issue (to add information, when clicking on the model thumbnail it calls `SetPlaceableModel` in the `Update()` from a different script). ***Also***, it now seems to be working properly *only for the first model that is is placed*, then it behaves with the problem I'm having (but I don't know why... I haven't changed anything).

### I've tried...

As I mentioned, I've tried calling `SetPlaceableModel` again after placing a model, I've tried doing `Instantiate` on the `Texture` and `Material` as is [suggested here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/45692/how-to-independently-change-textures-on-clones-in.html) (which seems to be my exact issue... so I must be missing something). **

I am super confused... please help. If you need any more information let me know.

---

### **

**EDIT**: on further testing (I added a new model and 2 `TextureSet` objects to go with it, so I had 2 models each with 2 different texture sets), this 'works' because the issue only arises **after the first time I change textures *after* selecting a model**. The issue goes away when I change models and use the material/texture that are default on the model (each model has material(s)/texture(s) on them, set in the Editor, before running the project).

**EDIT 2**: as @Programmer suggested, I changed the `Instantiate(material) as Material` to his suggested `new Material(material)`, but it did not work. This is how I implemented it:

```
public void ChangeGhostTextures(TextureSet textureSet)
{
    var materials = Ghost.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>().SelectMany(x => x.materials);
    foreach (var texture in textureSet.Textures.Where(x => !x.name.ToLower().Contains("normal")))
    {
        var normalTexture = textureSet.Textures.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == string.Format("{0}_Normal", texture.name));
        foreach (var material in materials.Where(x => x.name.Replace(" (Instance)", string.Empty) == texture.name))
        {
            material.SetTexture("_MainTex", texture);
            if (normalTexture != null)
            {
                material.SetTexture("_BumpMap", normalTexture);
            }
            var _material = new Material(material);
            var assignableMaterial = materials.First(x => x.Equals(material));
            assignableMaterial = _material;
        }
    }
}
```

did I do something wrong? I tried this implementation, too, but it doesn't change textures at all now (whereas the other implementation does change textures, but maintains the issue):

```
var _material = new Material(material);
_material.SetTexture("_MainTex", texture);
if (normalTexture != null)
{
    _material.SetTexture("_BumpMap", normalTexture);
}
var assignableMaterial = materials.First(x => x.Equals(material));
assignableMaterial = _material;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't get this to work with @Programmer's method (though it may work for others, mine was still changing the material, no matter where/how I implemented `var _mat = new Material(mat);` or assigned textures, I opted to just define multiple materials as Assets and switch between them as desired:

```
public void ChangeGhostMaterials(MaterialSet materialSet)
{
    foreach (var renderer in Ghost.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>())
    {
        var material = materialSet.Materials.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name.Equals(renderer.material.name.Replace(" (Instance)", string.Empty)));
        renderer.material = material ?? renderer.material;
    }
}
```

If someone else comes along this and provides a working Answer, I will gladly change the selected Answer, but as it stands this is my solution to my issue.

Answer (score 1):

> when I Instantiate the Ghost onto the Plane, the materials seem to be
>   maintaining reference to the Ghost materials.

There are three constructor overloads for the Material class:

```
public Material(string contents);
public Material(Shader shader);
public Material(Material source);
```

The last is what you need. Use it to make a copy of your original material then assign that copy to your object. This should solve the material reference issues.

```
public Material objMat;

void Start()
{
    Material newMat = new Material(objMat);
    //Use the newMat on your object
}
```

Comment: So, instead of doing the `Instantiate(material) as Material` way, do it the constructor way? Could you elaborate on why `Instantiate` doesn't break the reference but the constructor does? (am I just dumb and blanking on a fundamental concept?) Thanks, will test!

Comment: It's how Unity function. They did that to save memory. Imaging the amount of data that will be created if you instantiate the-same type of GameObject many times, especially when they have many textures(albedo, normal, transparency and so on). The materials are always shared. Now, if you try to modify that material, for example, change the color of it, it will create new instance of that material for you and automatically break the reference connection. My solution shows how to do that manually so that you don't have to modify the material to get it to do that foe you

Comment: @Daevin Alternatively, look into [`MaterialPropertyBlock`s](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.html)

Comment: @Draco18s OP is trying to break the connection between the materials. `MaterialPropertyBlock` is meant to do the opposite.

Comment: Thanks, but I just tested this and it is still changing the models that are already places ***and*** the `Ghost` model, so this did not fix my issue. Unless I implemented it incorrectly? See my edit for my implementation.

Comment: @Programmer Yes, but its possible that a `MaterialPropertyBlock` can achieve the desired *visual outcome* without the extra memory overhead.

Comment: @Draco18s I'm a little new to Unity, and a lot new to manipulating materials/textures... could you post an answer with a code example? (preferably with my code as a basis so I don't get lost/miss something)

Comment: @Daevin I don't understand your `ChangeGhostTextures` code well enough to do so (or to figure out why it's not working).

Comment: @Draco18s haha fair enough. I appreciate you pointing me that way. But for posterity, essentially what I'm doing is iterating over each `Texture` in the set I want applied to a model, then iterating over each `Material` in that model that has the same(ish) name as the `Texture`, then applying the `Texture` to that `Material` (so you can change some but not all `Texture`s/`Material`s if the you don't want it to). I found [this post](https://answers.unity.com/questions/411601/change-the-color-of-a-material-for-only-one-object.html) with your help, so I'm investigating what that suggests. Thanks!

Comment: @Daevin `MaterialPropertyBlocks` lets you reuse the same `Material` instance, but with changed parameters (textures, colors, etc) and you only need to apply them once (iirc). Uses less memory, doesn't break batching, and doesn't cause excess GC from multiple changes to the same Material.

Comment: @Draco18s I've been investigating using the `MaterialPropertyBlock` object, but it appears that you can only assign one to the `Renderer`, but I have multiple materials on the model that are being changed so this won't work (without a costly workaround). Unless you know how to implement it with multiple `Material`s on a `Renderer`?

Comment: @Programmer since your answer isn't working, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @Daevin Ah, I didn't realize there were *multiple separate materials* on the *same renderer.* Yeah, that would make things tricky. And no, I don't. :\

Comment: This is a bit old, but I'm still left wondering how Instantiate(material) is different from new Material(material). Maybe this is a holdover from and older version of unity, but 2018 isn't that long ago. When I use Instantiate(), I still get a material instance rather than the original material. Unfortunately, I don't have the unity source code so it's hard to see what the exact differences might be.